# Detect HDMI and Start GUI

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero

We build an applications that supports a server mode and a GUI mode. Now the XServer and the application  should start, if a HDMI Cable is connected otherwise it should only run the server.

So whats the best way to detect HDMI?  Read the resolution and if it's not default HDMI resolution  it's connected?  But this wouldn't be possible if the PI had booted already, wouldn't it?

Comment: It may be simpler to test the runlevel using the runlevel command. if running in runlevel 5 would impy a gui supported setup. Then you could launch the GUI as part of the GUI startup.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Checking the runlevel would be A) Depreciated, B) Not necessarily indicative of whether X is running.   I didn't check, but I'd bet what happens with a GUI system with no display attached is X starts, finds no display, and exits.  However, the runlevel (or non-depreciated equivalent) would still remain the same, so if you wanted a system that could be configured to use a GUI when available that's not a useful test...

Comment: ...You can definitely get detailed information from the output of the X server -- however in fact the output of `systemctl status ______` would probably be the easiest and most decisive thing to parse here.  Probably there's a python API :P  And to query the X server for the displays and resolution (also see `man xargs`).

Answer (score 11):

There's a command line utility, `tvservice` built into Raspbian that will tell you the state of the HDMI.

To detect the full state, you can use the command: `tvservice -s`. On my RPi this currently outputs:

```
state 0x40001 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced
```

The states (that I've gathered) are as follows:

- `0x40001` Not initialized and HDMI cable is disconnected
- `0x40002` Not initialized but HDMI cable is connected
- `0x120002` Standby mode
- `0x120005` HDMI disconnected
- `0x120016` Active

If you're less interested in the additional details `tvservice -n` may be slightly simpler to parse. It gives the current name of connected device. Example:

```
[E] No device present
```

Additionally, if connectivity is touch and go, you may find the `-M` flag useful. It monitors for events concerned with the HDMI port.

**Sources**:

- I think this is the [original forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=52309) I pulled the above states from in my notes.
- The [tvservice source code](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/tvservice)

**Edit:**

As Ghanima pointed out in the comments, tvservice is also available in Arch under `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice`.

Comment: On a side note, it's not just available an Raspbian. Arch has it to, it sits in `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice` and comes as part of the *raspberrypi-firmware-tools* package that is installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

The tvservice command does not consistently sense when HDMI is disconnected.  Say you boot the Pi with HDMI, then manaully disconnect the HDMI cable.  The tvservice command will still report that HDMI device is connected, in that -n, -s, etc. commands still report the last previously connected monitor via HDMI.